# Differentiate a function with respect to a vector

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

I'm reading my course on quantum mechanics and I just noticed something strange (or at least new to me) that I don't really understand :

$$\psi(\vec{r},t) = \psi_0 e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}(\vec{p}.\vec{r} -Et)}$$
$$\frac{d\psi}{d\vec{r}} = \frac{i\vec{p}}{\hbar}\psi \hspace{5mm}, \hspace 5mm\frac{d\psi}{dt} = -\frac{iE}{\hbar}\psi$$

I'm confused. I've never seen this notation $\frac{d\psi}{d\vec{r}}$ before (with the vector at the bottom). Usually, when there are vectors, I see grad, div, etc...

So what happened here ? Everything looks like the operation has been carried out by treating $\vec{r}$ like a simple variable and $\vec{p}$ like a simple constant, I didn't know that was possible. Exactly what rules have been applied here ? When can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation is just a very compact way of writing $$\frac{d\psi}{dr_k} = \frac{i p_k}{\hbar}\psi,~~~~~\text{for}~~~~~k=1,2,3$$ where $r_k,p_k$ is the $k$'th component of the vector $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{p}$ respectively. The derivatives in the equation above are the good old standard derivatives.

Comment: Can I summarize the two equations this way : $\nabla\psi = \frac{i}{\hbar}\psi(p_x, p_y, p_z, -E)$ ?

Comment: @user1234161 You could, but I would not use that notation since it is not normally used in non-relativisitic quantum mechanics where (I think) this problem is from. There $\nabla$ is usually the $3$-space gradient so that notation could be confusing. In some cases, where $4$-vectors are used, then such a notation could make sense.

Comment: It is indeed from non-relativistic QM. I'm going to follow your advice and keep using the course's notation for the time being then. Thanks :)